# What is the name of this droid?

Tags: star-wars, character-identification, the-mandalorian

In the offices where Pershing works there is a very grumpy droid. We also see the same droid in episode 5 of season 3.

[image]

Is this droid in some way related to C1-10P from Rebels? They seem to have the same personality.

Comment: I'm almost tending towards an R0, but https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/R0-4L0 they don't seem to have the lower 'monocle' eye. R5s also have the same vague head shape, and there's mentions of arms but there's nothing with the angled, not dome head and the R2 style silver monocle. All the C series droids I can find in a quick search are bipedal, so I'm leaning towards a 'new' R series

Comment: Also both the C series droids I can find are somewhat shorter in torso. Chopper's got a third wheel that looks bolted on and the CH-33P has a dome head. That's almost certainly a R series droid. The tray looks bolted on too - so the poor dear really *can't* do any more than unload the tray onto a flat surface. No wonder they're cranky ._.

Comment: We've all had soul crushing jobs like that...

Comment: https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Astromech_droid there's a group image here with a teal one on the back right that's a match

Comment: I just found [this image](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/R6_astromech?file=R6D8-SWZ.png) that looks VERY familar.

Comment: In Legends canon the R6 series premiered sometime after the Battle of Endor with a combination of the conical R5 head and the R2 eye, as an attempt by Industrial Automaton to get back into their former droid-selling numbers (the R3 series was too specialized, the R4 was intended for farm/office work instead of starfighter maintenance, and the R5 was a mistake. Just a mistake. A terrible mistake.) In Disney canon they've been confirmed as being in Mando's time frame too. If OP is asking for the individual droid's name/number, I'm sure it's given somewhere and there'll be a toy of it soon.

Answer (score 3):

That specific droid hasn't been named in anything published yet (for obvious reasons) but it seems to be an [R6 Unit](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/R6_astromech), a design that first started showing up in canon in the Sequel trilogy (though it dates all the way back to the old WEG Adventure Journals.) So no, there's no reason to think it has anything to do with Chopper. He's a C1 Unit, which is a much older Republic era model.

As for their respective personalities: leaving aside for a moment the fact we haven't seen enough of this droid to get any real sense of it's personality beyond perhaps "mildly passive aggressive"; droids that exhibit distinct personalities generally seem to do so because of their unique histories. Their models have little to nothing to do with it.
Plus if his personality was really anything like Choppers', his pushing that tray of datacards onto that already crowded desk would have been accompanied by much more maniacal cackling, and probably upturned furniture.